# Git hook to send email notification on repo changes

Tags: git, githooks

How do I configure the appropriate Git hook to send a summary email whenever a set of changes is pushed to the upstream repository?

Comment: For version update (new label) for any git repo you can use https://www.git-notifier.com to send Email notifications (free) or SMS notifications (Paid)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Another, more modern way to do this is with [git-multimail](https://github.com/git-multimail/git-multimail), as suggested by [Chords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552360/git-push-email-notification/552362?noredirect=1#comment29250514_552362) below.

---

*This is how you did it in 2009.*

You could add something like [this](http://source.winehq.org/git/tools.git/?a=blob;f=git-notify;hb=HEAD) to your post-receive hook in $GITDIR/hooks, or use the script in the contrib directory of the source [(Available here)](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=contrib/hooks/post-receive-email;h=60cbab65d3f8230be3041a13fac2fd9f9b3018d5;hb=HEAD)

Comment: If I reference that script in my hooks, does the referenced script have to reside on the upstream host or locally?

Comment: The host that is executing the hook, so in the case of a post-receive, the upstream host (whereas a post-commit hook would need the script on the host you're running the commit on).

Comment: Ahhh, but you can accept the answer and you'll both get more reputation!

Comment: The part that got me was setting the recipients list. I finally figured it out that you need to use git config: git config hooks.mailinglist "person1@example.com, person2@example.com"

Comment: It's worth noting that the link in this answer is no longer under active development. Instead, use [multimail](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/contrib/hooks/multimail/README?id=HEAD), which is mentioned in the readme.

Comment: @Chords Does "no longer under active development" mean that it cannot be used anymore?

Answer (score 19):

Here is the simplest solution I've found:

1) Log in to your gitHub account on [github.com](http://github.com)

2) In the main tab click on **Settings**

3) From the main navigation choose **Service Hooks**

4) From Available Hooks choose Email

5) Fill in your email address in field **Address**

6) Check the checkbox **Send from Author**

7) Check the checkbox **Active**

8) Click on **Update Settings**

Optional: You can click on **Test Hook** for testing, check your inbox you should receive email.

Also there are images made according to the process:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And now for the **grand final** I have the answer which is tested and approved at my side.

**How to send email to ALL development team members, when gitHub's Service Hooks->Email allows only at most 2 recipients }**.

The answer is combination of **Service Hook->Email @ GitHub && Google groups**

1. First login to your google account
2. Go to [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com) and at the top click on **Create Group**
3. Type in Group Name, Group email address (will copy/paste into GitHub
   Service Hook->Email Address), Group description
4. After that hit Create button at the top, your new group should be
   created now
5. After that in the menu to the left hit **Invite members** and type
   in the email addresses of your team mates
6. After that hit **Send invites** (when your members accept
   invitation) they are now formally members of this group
7. In the menu on the left click on **All Members** and check the 4th
   column called **Delivery**, every team member should have option
   **All Email**.
8. After that I would like to credit **Mr. Clement Escoffier** and
   please do follow his guidelines @ [Clement Escoffier::Send Github commits to a Google Group](http://www.dynamis-technologies.com/blog/send-github-commits-to-a-google-group/#comment-35) on how to
   finish it. {Thank you Clement :)}
9. If the link becomes unavailable here is another link to my gDocs @
   [PDF version of Clements guide](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8JbMMVJ5rsVSGRqVk11bFZ6MVE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is a github solution. Nothing in the question tells me that the user are using github. Looks like it is a perfect answer for a question on github though.

Comment: This email service is going to discontinued after Oct 2018. So this answer is not valid after that point.  https://developer.github.com/changes/2018-04-25-github-services-deprecation/

Answer (score 10):

This is my way of send email notification to users every time some one push to the repository.

[Setting Up Git Commit Email Notification](https://www.systutorials.com/1473/setting-up-git-commit-email-notification/)

It's based on Andy Parkins's scripts. I change it to used SMTP to send email. Of course, gmail's SMTP can also be used.

Answer (score 6):

[Robin Sommer](http://www.icir.org/robin)'s [git-notifier](http://www.icir.org/robin/git-notifier/) generates also very nice summaries in the following format:

```
Subject: [git/git-notifier] master: Adding www target to Makefile. (7dc1f95)

Repository : ssh://<removed>/git-notifier

On branch  : master

>---------------------------------------------------------------

commit 7dc1f95c97275618d5bde1aaf6760cd7ff6a6ef7
Author: Robin Sommer <robin@icir.org>
Date:   Sun Dec 19 20:21:38 2010 -0800

    Adding www target to Makefile.

>---------------------------------------------------------------

 Makefile |    6 ++++++
 1 files changed, 6 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

diff --git a/Makefile b/Makefile
index e184c66..9c9951b 100644
--- a/Makefile
+++ b/Makefile
@@ -5,6 +5,8 @@ VERSION   = 0.1

 DISTFILES = git-notifier README COPYING

+WWW = $(HOME)/www/git-notifier
+
 all:

 dist:
@@ -13,3 +15,7 @@ dist:
    cp $(DISTFILES) git-notifier-$(VERSION)
    tar czvf git-notifier-$(VERSION).tgz git-notifier-$(VERSION)
    rm -rf git-notifier-$(VERSION)
+
+www: dist
+   rst2html.py README >$(WWW)/index.html
+   cp git-notifier-$(VERSION).tgz $(WWW)
```

Answer (score 4):

setting hooks.showrev is making no distinguishable difference? :-/

Sample conf:

```
# less users/cj.git/config 
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = true
[hooks]
        mailinglist = cj@yoga.ee
        showrev = "git show -C %s; echo"
        emailprefix = "[sabu gitosis server] "
```

Comment: Ah, turns out the git.kernel.org version respected hooks.showrev, but default git installation script didn't! Just replaced the script, chmod a+x and then it works! Still need to understand the showrev syntax though

Comment: Similar issues with showing diffs here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804601/git-post-receive-email-hook-including-diff-patches/1790161#1790161

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this, but had to opt for using the contrib script, not the other (perl) script by Alexandre Julliard. It seems fancier and more configurable, but with postfix I had no mail command which would accept "-s"? Here's my way:

http://pastie.textmate.org/695323

It would be nice to show some more info, like the full patch, gitweb link and commit graph as well, but this script can only do the first - if I play around with hooks.showrev it seems.

Anyway, cheers and thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

If you use windows, [scm-notifier](https://github.com/pocorall/scm-notifier) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a full answer since it is Github-specific, but if you happen to use Github it is extremely easy to configure "Service Hooks".
For each repository you wish to monitor, enter Settings / Service Hooks.
There are plenty of available integrations, such as Trac, Twitter, Amazon SNS, Jira, Asana, Bugzilla, FogBugz, IRC, Jabber, Pivotal Tracker, Trello and Email....
Simply select email and feed it with a group email address.
We use the email notifications to sync our developers.

Answer (score 0):

If you use GitLab you can use the 'Email-on-push' project service for this, it can be found under services in project settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pre-commit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'mail'

Mail.defaults do
  delivery_method :smtp,
    address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    user_name: '...',
    password: '...',
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
end

changes=`git diff --cached --unified=0 Gemfile Bowerfile`

unless changes.empty?
  Mail.deliver do
    from     '...'
    to       '...'
    subject  '[PROJECT] Plese confirm team can use libraries'
    body     changes
  end
end
```

Install:

```
cd project
cp pre-commit .git/hooks
chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit
gem install mail
```

Test:

```
echo "# some change" >> Gemfile && git commit -m 'some change' Gemfile
```

Answer (score 0):

In **GitLab** under your repository:

1. Click on Setting.
2. When setting expands there you will see **Integrations**. Click on
   it.

There opens a new page **Emails on push**

3. Locate and select **Send from committer**.
4. Also, enter the **Recipients** with comma separated located at the
   last field.

Also there is an option for **Disable code diffs** which exclude possibly sensitive code diffs in notification body. It is optional.

For more details:
Click [Here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/emails_on_push.html#:~:text=From%20the%20Integrations%20page%20select,a%20push%20event%20is%20received.)