# How to notify push events sending mail for git on Window?

Tags: git, email, versioning

I searched through internet but I could not find anything.

Is it possible to send notification emails for each GIT's push events to all the participants?

if yes, could you give me some tips?

Comment: If you're using GitHub, you can also use their service hooks. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16223666/2200259

Comment: no I'm not, just a server in which I have installed GIT

Answer (score 2):

You could try using post-hooks to send email notifications to users every time the repository is pushed. [Setting Up Git Commit Email Notification](http://www.fclose.com/b/linux/1473/setting-up-git-commit-email-notification/)

Comment: The problem is that I need that on Windows and not on Linux :(