# Git Status/Track remote repo // Edited

Tags: git

**The gist:**

Essentially, what I need to make everyone feel more comfortable with git:

1. For each, individual devs' `git status` to be visible by the other devs.
2. Some sort of trigger or hook on `git add` - hopefully, for making better use of 'staging' and also for seeing the mistakes our less-experienced developer(s) make initially -- so we can guide them a bit instead of them quietly floudering through a relatively simple thing.

At this moment, I don't see a way to do this aside from having a monitor that has tiled display of an SSH on each machine with `$watch git status` -- and an alias for `git add` that makes a copy of the file into two places -- the local, development server, and into code-reviewer's inbox.

However, since Git does tracking, I'm sure that there's a better way to do this.

**A bit more info:**

I work with a team of three to four developers, depending on the project, and currently, I am in the process of migrating us over to Git.

Some of the team are reluctant to transition to Git (despite the previous chaos / primitive-nature of the system they had before), they all know the basics.

I've set up Git on all of their machines - with `git-daemon`, listening on 9418.

Is there any way to do this? Or perhaps I will need to kajigger something else -?

Or perhaps there is an entirely better way to approach this -?

Any insight or guidance is greatly appreciated, as I am somewhat new to Git, myself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up some client-side and/or server-side [Git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to send you an email or run a particular script when certain actions are performed. [Here's a list of the different types of hooks](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) that are available.

This question deals with something similar: [git push email notification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/552360/718972)

Comment: Yes, I've looked into these, but we're in need of something that can be triggered a bit earlier... 
I thought of writing an alias for `git add` - that would do something like - copy the file to another repo, `commit -a -m "automatic"` and push to their respective branch on a centralized server -- But not only is that needlessly complicated, but it doesn't solve the fact I'm working with foagie devs that are probably going to make one commit a day e_e. 
Perhaps Git-SVN would be better-? Or maybe a taser under their chair that goes off every hour if they don't make a stage or commit.

Answer (score 1):

Is this "Big Brother" implementation question? There is no way you can get remote status info on someone else's work except if that someone lets you change his bash aliases and override his git add or even implement watch function that sends you an email on every save, but that is basically privacy issue since git is fully distributed and until push happens all is offline.

Comment: Not entirely...  
The team is generally used to having a "Pulled List" - and while git negates the need for such a thing, people cling to their ways. I was more or less hoping to be able to generate a list of pulled files per user - so that they could at least have that comfort. (They have the most absurd objections to git) - And by watching how often they commit, I can prod them into the habbit of it, and next time something breaks, we'll actually have a changelog to refer to. But anyway, I think it would be generally useful to have a script fire on `git add` --