# how to request pull request from a particular remote in git?

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-pull, git-remote

This is how my config file of git looks:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = false
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:XXXXXXX/training.test.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "upstream"]
        url = https://github.com/YYYYYYY/training.test.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

The `remote` "origin" points to my github account
The `remote` "upstream" points to a different github account from where I forked into mine.

Q1: so everytime I do a `git pull`, it will `pull` from my `remote` (which is "origin").
how will I do a `git pull` of the `remote upstream` .

Q2: any changes I `commit and push` to my repository, the other user "YYYYY" must be notified for a pull request. how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `git pull remoterepo remotebranch[:localbranch]` (e.g.`git pull upstream foo:bar` , `git pull pustream foo`)

   or `git checkout --track upstream/remotebranch` if your local repo has no such a branch named `remotebranch`

   you can use `git branch -r` to show the remote branchs.
2. you can use [github webhook](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks)

Comment: This did not work: `git pull upstream/master
fatal: 'upstream/master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: Is means that there is no branch name master in your `upstream` repo. So what branch in upstream you want to pull. e.g. `git pull upstream/foo master`

Comment: so try to use `git branch -r` to see the remote branchs.:)

Comment: when I do `git branch -r`, I see the `upstream/master`, but `git pull upstream/master` fails

Comment: I am sorry.. Not `git pull upstream/master` but `git pull upstream master`

Comment: or `git checkout --track upstream/master` if your local repo has no branch named `master`

Answer (score 0):

1. `git pull upstream branchname`, you can get a complete list of remote branchs by `git branch -a`
2. you could config hook in git repository to notify all the members in a project after a push, see [here](http://www.fclose.com/1473/setting-up-git-commit-email-notification/) and [here](http://www.janosgyerik.com/send-email-notification-on-commits-to-a-git-repository/)

ps. about Q2, you can find a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552360/git-push-email-notification/16223666#16223666), which provides other solutions

Comment: This does not work: I get this error : ` You asked to pull from the remote 'upstream', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line`.

Comment: @user1988876 then you should use `git pull upstream master`, you can use `git branch -a` to see a complete list of where you can pull from