# Push email configuration on git - Windows

Tags: windows, git, version-control, versioning

**Curent status**

Hi Team, i am using `Git` as version control on `Windows`. I have created a bare repository on Windows and also have client/developers, which have cloned from that repository, in th same `OS`.

**Problem**

So now can you please tell me how do i configure `email notification` when ever there is a `push` happens to repository.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552360/git-push-email-notification

Comment: Tried that sir, but could not make it. It's not for windows probably. Can you please help me on this.

Comment: sorry, didn't see that it not for windows.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can write a hook which sends you an E-Mail

Here is a good article how to implement it. Under Windows its a problem because you need a MTA. Perhaps you have a look at [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) and use gitolite as your gitkeeper. There you can implement some hooks and you have a centrilized place for your Git-Repositories.

http://www.fclose.com/1473/setting-up-git-commit-email-notification/

Comment: My windows machine should have the `mailx` mail server installed right to send mails. How can i do that. How do i do it?

Comment: Moreover how to make `post-receive` executable in windows