# How configure Github to get notifications for any new commit for any specific repository?

Tags: git, github

About Github - through the web browser (https://github.com) - for any repository available on GitHub, about *notifications*, I am able to do the following:

[image]

[image]

So far until here I am able to get notified through my github account that a new reply of an issue created by me is available **and** that a new release of the project is available. I need these two *specific* notifications types. Until here I am ok.

But I need other *specific* configuration/setting, is get a notification about when a commit was accomplished such as:

[image]

From above I want to be notified about any new commit (where a new release is not available yet).

Is possible accomplish that? How? I tried to find that option, but seems does not exist.

**Note**: I tried `All Activity` but this approach subscribes me to any issue arised, and fills the notifications report with a lot of info that I don't need, and of course it happens for each repository where I apply this option. If you are thinking to suggest to work through a GUI client, such as GitHub Desktop, I am following/watching many repositories, so, has no sense for me, be checking or viewing each one through the IDE

Comment: Git hooks could be of some help here . You can search for `post-commit-hooks` and triggering mails using these hooks from your repo . Also check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/q/552360/6309111

Comment: Are you an admin of this repository, or are you just a bystander?

Comment: Any repository was forked and cloned. I am not an admin. Of course, about to contribute to any of them

Comment: Unfortunately it seems this is not currently an option (?)

Answer (score 0):

For public repo, every branch has it's own commit rss subscribe link.
For example, git's master branch commit rss link
https://github.com/git/git/commits/master.atom

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is monitor **any** commit across **all** the branches for a SPECIFIC repository then follow the steps given below.

Simply login to following url and add your email here as shown

```
https://github.com/<user_name>/<repository_name>/settings/notifications
```

[image: Subscribe to live push requests to github]

[image: Subscribe to live push requests to github]

Now you can add your email and it'll subscribe to all the **push** events.

You'll get the emails like in the following format for all commits across any of the branches.
[image: Email Received format]

You can learn more about github email delivery notifications [here](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/managing-subscriptions-and-notifications-on-github/setting-up-notifications/configuring-notifications#customizing-your-email-notifications).

Comment: Let me test it soon as I can. Thank You