# How to send a email when git pushed

Tags: git

I'm evaluating git now.
I expected that sending email when commit and push to remote repository.
But couldn't catch email.
I registered my email address and username.
But I couldn't find post-receive and post-receive-email file anywhere.

Please teach me how to get post-receive and  post-receive-email file
or teach me example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git hook to send email notification on repo changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552360/git-hook-to-send-email-notification-on-repo-changes)

Comment: Is this using plain git or do you have form of repository management system in place? (such as github, gitlab, gerrit, bitbucket)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Remote repository is put on usual nas storage.

Comment: Presumably you control the NAS, so @Nadar's suggestion is the right one.